# How to get the values of Sent and Received LAN data?

Tags: windows-xp, command-line, lan, network-traffic

Is there any command that shows me the amount of data sent and received, same as **Sent** and **Received** data for my LAN connection (picture bellow)?

I need to pipe this info into a file for further use.

[image]

Comment: What do you want: copy all data that is sent over the network, or do you want to monitor network traffic?

Comment: WMI objects (_maybe something under performance data?_) might come handy for monitoring... and `wmic` is commandline interface to WMI.

Comment: From what I understand, he would like to parse those two values.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
netsh interface ip show ipstats
```

this will give you a table with information about received, sent, dropped packets and more.

Comment: it says: "The following command was not found: interface ip show ipstate."

my OS: Windows XP sp2 x64

Comment: @wiki It should work for Windows XP. I tried it under Windows 7 and it worked. Read the [Using Netsh Technet Article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490939.aspx) for details.

Comment: It should probably be `ipstats` not `ipstate`...

Comment: @Sampo thanks! That happens when you don't copy & paste ;-).

Comment: @wiki I updated my answer. There was a typo in the command!

Comment: "netsh interface ip show ipstats"

cmd resualt:

The Routing and Remote Access Service is not currently running on the local mach
ine.
Please use 'net start remoteaccess' on the machine to start the service.

Comment: @wiki did you try `net start remoteaccess` and then again `netsh interface ip show ipstats`? What was the result?

Answer (score 0):

You should have specified which version of Windows but the following command should work:

```
net statistics Workstation
```

Gives output like:

```
Workstation Statistics for \\NETBIOSNAME


Statistics since 18/04/2013 6:37:30 PM


  Bytes received                               438062
  Server Message Blocks (SMBs) received        4351
  Bytes transmitted                            537108
  Server Message Blocks (SMBs) transmitted     4346
  Read operations                              0
  Write operations                             0
  Raw reads denied                             0
  Raw writes denied                            0

  Network errors                               0
  Connections made                             312
  Reconnections made                           0
  Server disconnects                           0

  Sessions started                             1
  Hung sessions                                0
  Failed sessions                              0
  Failed operations                            0
  Use count                                    467
  Failed use count                             0
```

Comment: This command only gives information about data sent / received concerning network shares (SMB).